# Showing preimage of any subspace of $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Let $F:V\rightarrow U$ be a linear transformation. We have to show that the preimage of any subspace of $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

**My proof:**

Say $W$ is a subspace of $Im(F)$ and $T$ is a subspace of $V$. Now consider $u,w\in W$, such that there exist $v,p\in T$, such that $F(v)=u, F(p)=w$. $u+w\in W$ as it is a subspace, $$u+w=F(v)+F(p)=F(v+p)$$
We have this by linearity. Now $v+p\in T$, so the preimage of $W$ is a subspace. $F(0)=0$. $0\in W,T$ as these are subspaces.

Proof verification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, your answer is wrong as it is possible that a subspace of $U$ is not contained $Im(T)$ (i.e. whenever $T$ is not surjective).

You have to start with a subspace of $U$, not one that is a subspace of $Im(T)$.

---

As promised, **here is a proof**.

Let $W$ be a subspace of $U$. We will show that $F^{-1}(W)$ is a subspace of $V$.

Since $F(0) = 0 \in W$, we know that $0 \in F^{-1}(W)$.

Now, let $x,y \in F^{-1}(W) := \{v \in V: Fv \in W\}$, let $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$. Then $Fx, Fy \in W$, and hence $F(x + \lambda y) = F(x) + \lambda F(y) \in W$, as $W$ is a subspace. It follows that $x + \lambda y \in F^{-1}(W)$, and we can conlude that $U$ is indeed a subspace of $V$.

Comment: I did that initially. But I felt that you can't talk about the preimage of something that isn't in the image set. That's why I edited my proof. Also only subspaces of $Im(F)$ will have a preimage in $V$.

Comment: That's not true. Preimage is certainly defined for sets that aren't contained in the image.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that. What would be the preimage of $u\in U$ when there isn't a $v\in V$ for which $F(v)=u$, specifically what would be the preimage of $(1,1,1)$ when $F$ maps all elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar that would be the empty set, since there is no element which maps to $(1,1,1)$ under $F$.

Comment: The emptyset in this case, but that transformation is not linear.

Comment: Recall that for $A \subseteq U, T^{-1}(U) = \{v \in V : Tv \in U\}$. This is a concept that is defined for functions in general, and not restricted to functions that have an inverse.

Comment: @Math_QED the zero transformation is certainly linear.

Comment: I misread of course you are right.

Comment: The empty set is certainly not a subspace though.

Comment: A singelton that does not contain zero is no subspace either, so there is no counterexample.

Comment: Does the proof work is I change $Im(F)$ to $U$? Because any subspace of $U$ will always contain ${0}$ and so the there will always be ${0}$ in the preimage set. So $T$ will always contain $0$ even if it is preimage from complete $U$.

Comment: It doesnt work. You cant find elements in the domain that gets mapped to chosen points in the codomain if you pick points outside the image. I will write out an answer in the evening. Now I have to conquer an exam of functional analysis first :P

Comment: As promised, I included a proof. Let me know if something is unclear.